# QTextEdit corners do not follow the border boundaries assigned in style sheet

Tags: python, pyqt5, border, pyside2, qtextedit

How to correct sharp corners of a `QTextEdit` widget applied in **style sheet**?
Corners of the `QTextEdit` being inside the **border**'s boundaries is the purpose.

[image]

```
# importing libraries
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PySide2.QtCore import *
import sys

class Scene(QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self, _scene_width, _scene_height):
        super(Scene, self).__init__()
        self.setSceneRect(0, 0, _scene_width, _scene_height)
        map_center = _scene_width / 2
        te = QTextEdit()
        te.setStyleSheet(" border-radius: 30px;background-clip: border; background-color: rgb(220, 220,220); color: rgb(113, 113, 113); font: 14pt Vazir; border:4px solid; border-color: rgb(255,95,95);")
        te.insertPlainText("Test Text")
        te.setGeometry(map_center, map_center, 100, 100)
        self.addWidget(te)


class View(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, _scene_width, _scene_height):
        super(View, self).__init__()
        self.scale_factor = 1
        self.scene_width = _scene_width
        self.scene_height = _scene_height
        scene = Scene(_scene_width, _scene_height)
        self.setScene(scene)
        self.showMaximized()

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = View(1000, 1000)
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Result of the code

[image]

Comment: Is this text edit added to a widget [layout] or is it a top level window? And if it's not, did you set a stylesheet to any of its parent widgets?

Comment: @musicamante It is added to a `QGraphicsScene`. No.

Comment: The fact that you were adding the widget to a QGraphicsScene is an important aspect you should have mentioned. What happens if you use `te.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_NoSystemBackground, True)`?

Comment: @musicamante `te.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_NoSystemBackground, True)` didn't help; everything except `QTextEdit`'s text got disappeared. I've updated the question to make it easier to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding widgets to a graphics scene makes things a bit more complicated.

The problem is that widgets without any parent are treated as top level widgets ("windows") are: even if you set a rounded border around them, the widget will still have a rectangular shape, and that shape will always be drawn using the background role palette of the widget, including what's outside the rounded edges.

Since you are using stylesheets, one thing that can be done is to set the background palette role to `transparent` (this works since you're specifying the background in the stylesheet and that background will be clipped to the border):

```
        palette = te.palette()
        palette.setBrush(palette.Window, QBrush(Qt.transparent))
        te.setPalette(palette)
```

Note that this might *not* be enough, as some styles (notably, the Oxygen style) add a default background alpha gradient to the palette while painting the widget, and there's almost nothing you can do about that, at least in this situations.

In that case, as with top level windows, you need to set a [mask](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setMask) on the widget. Consider that masks are *bit* maps, meaning that **no** aliasing is applied: the pixels are drawn or they are not.

```
        mask = QPainterPath()
        # the rectangle needs a 1 pixel adjustment to ensure that the aliasing is
        # correctly drawn, with the drawback of showing partial background pixels
        mask.addRoundedRect(QRectF(te.rect()).adjusted(-1, -1, 1, 1), 30, 30)
        te.setMask(QRegion(mask.toFillPolygon(QTransform()).toPolygon()))
```

Finally, some important considerations:

- stylesheets should be always used with care, as they should usually be considered for special "exceptions" only, as their behavior might be erratic;
- using large values for border radius is not suggested, as it might clip other contents (most importantly, the scroll bars);
- some styles apply the stylesheet parameters in different ways, especially with QAbstractScrollArea subclasses (like QTextEdit); for example, with Oxygen style, i get the rounded border *inside* the text area contents, while I don't get it in the Windows style;
- it's usually good practice to use specific syntax in stylesheets, meaning that you should specify the widget *class* (which is important for widgets containing subwidgets like QTextEdit) and provide correct indentation:

```
        te.setStyleSheet('''
            QTextEdit {
                border-radius: 30px;
                background-clip: border;
                background-color: rgb(220, 220,220);
                color: rgb(113, 113, 113);
                font: 14pt Vazir;
                border:4px solid;
                border-color: rgb(255,95,95);
            }
        ''')
```

Comment: The **textedit** inside a **widget** and adding the **widget** to the **scene** solved the problem as you noted the problem of adding a **widget** directly to a **scene**. With this example code, no result with the **palette** approach. Using **mask** results in pixelated corners as you've explained. Thank you for the answer and for the extra considerations about **stylesheets**. One could skip many problems with these guides.

Comment: @Eftekhari as said, different styles apply stylesheets in slightly different ways; stylesheets are fundamentally overrides of what the underlying style does, so if the style draws the background with its own rules, no matter what palette is set, it will draw the background in some way. Note that as a workaround you could set a style for the QTextEdit only using `te.setStyle(QStyleFactory.create('stylename'))` based on the list returned by `QStyleFactory.keys()`. Generally, the "fusion" style (which should be available on Windows too) is the most standard and compliant.

Comment: Thanks. Now that it is needed to use widgets to add textedits into the scene and based on the fact that widgets are ram consuming, how could a scene have hundereds of widgets/textedits without the ram overflow? On zoomed-out state of the map it is needed for all the widgets/textedits to be visible to let the user to have a vast overall look on what is happening on the map (it is not the geographical map).

Comment: Qt has a pretty good memory management, and having hundreds of widgets is usually not an issue. Even with a thousand basic widgets (not item views, which are a bit more consuming especially with large models), the memory consumption would probably increase by just 5-10mb. Also, QGraphicsView and QGraphicsScene have good cpu/memory performance even with thousands of items (see the [40000 chips example](https://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qtwidgets-graphicsview-chip-example.html) and the only bottleneck is the eventual python implementation (usually when overriding `paint()` of a QGraphicsItem).